# Is it still possible to get @icloud.com email address?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

Set up a new iCloud account for someone and I am not seeing the option to set up an @icloud.com address and use the free email service. Does anyone know if this is still possible and how to go about doing this?

Comment: Does [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2620?locale=en_US) help?

Comment: "If you set up iCloud using an Apple ID that doesn’t end with icloud.com, me.com, or mac.com, you must set up an icloud.com email address before you can use iCloud Mail." It doesn't explain *how* to do it.

Comment: I can't do it, which is why I asked if the link helped, but do what the next line after that says... Go to Settings > iCloud and turn the mail switch on, I think that's the point you get to create it

Comment: I see what you mean now, I will try this later and update this thread. I do not remember having to set up mail on the physical device previously.

Comment: Go to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com), and click _"Create Your Now"_.

Comment: Confirmed, I just tried this on someone else's phone.  I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The steps seem strange, but first you must create your appleid using a non Apple address (note that if you already have an @icloud, @mac, or @me email address that email address is already an Apple ID)

Once your Apple ID has been created, on the device go to Settings > iCloud and flip the mail switch on, you will be prompted there to create your @icloud.com email address.

Alternatively, you can go to setting and go to mail. From there, add account and choose iCloud. If you choose "create Apple ID" at this screen, for whatever reason, it will allow you to create an "@icloud.com" email.

[source Apple kb](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2620?locale=en_US)

Comment: I just executed this instructions and they worked.

Answer (score 13):

Using a Mac:

System Preferences -> Internet Accounts -> (Maybe you need to click the +) -> Select iCloud on the right -> Create Apple ID -> Follow the steps

Also note that after entering your birthday, you should select "Get a free iCloud email address".

Answer (score 0):

iCloud accounts are different for different devices. If you are using iPhone, iPad or even an iPod Touch you can use iCloud. iCloud is Apple’s own icloud service which allows you to save all the data which is present on your iPhone on the online cloud. In order to use iCloud service, you will have to create icloud email address (@icloud.com).

Creating a **Free iCloud Email Address (@icloud.com)** is really a very simple task and it doesn't take much time.  Here's how to create @icloud.com email address on an iPhone or iPad device:

- From the Home screen of your device, select **Settings** option and tap
  on the **iCloud** button.
- If you are already logged in with any iCloud
  account then log out.
- After logged out, select **Sign in to your iPhone**
- On the screen to enter your Apple ID, select **Don't have an Apple ID or forgot it?**

  - Select **Create Apple ID**
    option.
- Now, enter your **Birthday**, **First Name** and **Last Name**.
- Select **Get a free iCloud email address**
- Now, enter the **username** which you want to use in your iCloud account.
- To set up an @icloud email address confirm the process by selecting the
  **Create Email Address** button.
- Enter a **Password** and confirm too.
- Now to secure your iCloud account, you must enter a phone number that can receive a text message or phone call
- Enter the verification code you receive via text or phone call
- Finally agree to the **Terms and Conditions**. That’s it!
- You have just created a free icloud email address. Now enjoy!!

Thus, you can see how simple is to create a free iCloud email address (@icloud.com).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Apple's iCloud service without creating an @icloud.com email account.   I've had an iCloud account for ten years, and it does not have an @icloud.com email address, or any other apple email address, associated with it. My suggestion is to not even do what you ask.

Comment: I’ve edited so it so it addresses the answer and not some other comment or question.